# conditional evaluation in TensorFlow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

This can be done with `tf.cond`, however it will update both branches of the graph, from the [manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond):

> Note that the conditional execution applies only to the operations
>   defined in true_fn and false_fn. Consider the following simple
>   program:

```
z = tf.multiply(a, b)
result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

> If `x < y`, the `tf.add` operation will be executed and tf.square
>   operation will not be executed. Since z is needed for at least one
>   branch of the cond, the `tf.multiply` operation is **always executed,
>   unconditionally**.

How can I implement this such that `tf.multiply` is executed conditionally (i.e. only when `x > Y`)?

More specifically, what I'm trying to do:

```
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4), trainable=False, name='var1')
update_var1 = tf.assign(var1,var1 +1)
training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def f1():
  with tf.control_dependencies([update_var1]):
    return var1*1.1

def f2():
  return var1 * 1.1

final = tf.cond(training, f1, f2)
sess.run(final, feed_dict={training:False})
```

This will increase var1 with 1 each time you evaluate final, regardless the value of `training`, and the problem lays in `tf.cond`, because manually it works:

```
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4), trainable=False, name='var1')
update_var1 = tf.assign(var1,var1 +1)
training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

with tf.control_dependencies([update_var1]):
  f1 = var1 * 1.1

f2 = var1 * 1.1

sess.run(f1)
>> array([1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1])
sess.run(f1)
>> array([2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2])
# var1 gets updated every call
sess.run(f2)
>> array([2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2])
sess.run(f2)
>> array([2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2])
# var1 does not get updated
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general solution is as follows: move the code that you want to execute conditionally **into the body of the `lambda`** (or—in general—the callable object) for the appropriate branch of the `tf.cond()`. For example, to ensure that `tf.multiply(a, b)` only executes when `x < y`, you move it into the `true_fn` lambda:

```
result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, tf.multiply(a, b)), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

The same principle can be applied to variable update ops, such as `tf.assign()`. The important detail is that you must create the `tf.assign()` op **inside the body of the function** used for one of the branches. Here's how you'd modify your second example:

```
var1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4), trainable=False, name='var1')
training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def f1():
  with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(var1, var1 + 1)]):
    return var1 * 1.1

def f2():
  return var1 * 1.1

final = tf.cond(training, f1, f2)
sess.run(final, feed_dict={training: False})
```

The control dependencies for the assignment are a little fiddly, so alternatively you could write `f1()` as:

```
def f1():
  return tf.assign(var1, var1 + 1) * 1.1
```

...or put the whole thing on one line as:

```
final = tf.cond(training, lambda: tf.assign(var1, var1 + 1) * 1.1, lambda: var1 * 1.1)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you need z as a variable, see more specific example in my question. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO you are changing the scope of the question. @mrry was spot on---I was to write the exact same answer. How about accepting his answer and create another question? I believe both would be relevant and useful.

Comment: The answer is wrong because tf.multiply still gets executed you just don't see it anymore because the intermediate value isn't stored anywhere. If the execution isn't a problem you could just as well store it in variable z and you're back where we started.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the execution of the function `tf.multiply()` (which is called during graph construction) with the execution of the op (which only executes when `x < y`). Either way, I've updated the answer to cover the modified question.

Comment: Whooha, that works! thanks! Still, for it to make sense,.. you say `tf.multiply()` get's called during construction only, then how comes in my example the update function gets called at each `tf.cond` evaluation (for both True and False cases)? And doesn't get evaluated in the 'manual' version?